# iOS app crash with SIGTRAP and _block_invoke

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash

the systemVersion: iOS 9.3.4 (13G35)

phone: iPhone 6

My app has a function can read address book, There is a user he click on the button to crash, but my iPhone 6s can run, So I am very confused. I don't know what happened. :-(

This is crash log:

## /#2 Thread

SIGTRAP

`0 CoreFoundation    CFRelease + 1128
    1 cardloan  __37+[AddressBookPage getAddressBookList]_block_invoke     (AddressBookPage.m:92)
    2 cardloan  __37+[AddressBookPage getAddressBookList]_block_invoke   (AddressBookPage.m:92)
    3 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    4 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_client_callout + 16
    5 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
6 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib   _pthread_wqthread + 1092`

This is my code:

```
    NSMutableArray *dataFileArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    // getAddressBook
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef results = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    NSInteger resultsCount = CFArrayGetCount(results);
    for(int i = 0; i < resultsCount; i++) {

        NSString *book;
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(results, i);

        ABMutableMultiValueRef name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);

        ABMutableMultiValueRef phone = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        NSMutableArray *phoneArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSInteger index = ABMultiValueGetCount(phone);
        for (int k = 0; k < index; k++) {
            CFStringRef phoneRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phone, k);
            [phoneArray addObject:(__bridge NSString *)(phoneRef)];
            CFRelease(phoneRef);
        }

        book = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", name, [phoneArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]];
        CFRelease(phone);
        CFRelease(name);
        [dataFileArray addObject:book]; //here is AddressBookPage.m:92

    }
    CFRelease(results);
    CFRelease(addressBook);
```

`

Comment: There can be a particular contact in your address book which might be causing the crash, while you fetch. Did you tried to find the exact line in the for loop to get where it is crashing. Add few NSLogs as you read person, name, phone etc to get the cause.

Comment: I annotate this three line :  CFRelease(phoneRef); CFRelease(phone); CFRelease(name);  and app run good